# Adding content to div in Bootstrap modal from server side in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I have input form in Bootstrap model popup. I want to show error message in div when submit button for saving. My model popup is in update panel. I am trying to do and its not working.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">SMTP Configuration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                Here is a input form

                <div id="ErrorDiv" class="required" runat="server">
                    This is a div where i want to show content

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Save" class="btn btn-success" ValidationGroup="Group1" />

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the server side method to show content.

```
public void ShowError(string Message)
{
    ErrorDiv.InnerHtml = Message;
    upModal.Update();
}
```

How can I show error content to div?

Comment: Could you share also the update panel?

Comment: All above code is in update panel..  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>    //All above code          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: is there anyone who will ans the above question?

Comment: take a look at this if helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579518/how-to-stop-on-the-sign-up-form-when-web-page-performs-postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open error model popup from Server side.
You need to update your Server side function ShowError to this.

```
public void ShowError(string Message)
{
    ErrorDiv.InnerHtml = Message;
    upModal.Update();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ErrorModel", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);
}
```

for this you have to put the div with id **myModal**, *into* **update panel**.

This will trigger jQuery function on Client side after server side execution complete and the model open manually.

> Other way to do this

If you **don't want to put model div into update panel** then follow this way.

Update your Model div like below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">SMTP Configuration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                Here is a input form

                <div id="ErrorDiv" class="required">
                    This is a div where i want to show content

                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Add JavaScript function as below into aspx file.

```
function showError(error){
    $("#ErrorDiv").html(error);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

And **call the JavaScript function from server side** like this

```
public void ShowError(string Message)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ErrorModel", "ShowError('"+Message+"');", true);
}
```

Here, you can explore more about [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @shomaail you have to add close button code  $('#myModal').modal('hide');

Comment: I did this but the grey background is not removed. Only the dialog box is removed